# Arduino can NOT send JSON

Tags: c++, json, arduino

I want so send data via a JSON object. All 7 variables you can see in the code should be well defined.

I get the following "error message"/incomplete JSON from Arduino monitor:

> {"topic":"Statistics","DrillDuration":"1000","SpeedToDrill":"20","SpeedWithObjectBefore":"100","SpeedWithObjectAfter":"100⸮⸮

Any idea? Is the package for my JSON too small?
I tested my function on a separate Arduino, where I cut my hole program. There it runs without any problems. This function "sendSummary" runs at the end of a bigger code, maybe this could lead to some issues?

Thanks a lot for your help!

```cpp
void sendSummary()
{
  const size_t capacity = JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(14);
  DynamicJsonDocument doc(capacity);

  doc["topic"] = "Statistics";
  doc["DrillDuration"] = DrillDuration;
  doc["SpeedToDrill"] = SpeedToDrill;
  doc["SpeedWithObjectBefore"] = SpeedWithObjectBefore;
  doc["SpeedWithObjectAfter"] = SpeedWithObjectAfter;
  doc["SpeedWithoutObject"] = SpeedWithoutObject;
  doc["DrillSpeed"] = DrillSpeedVar;

  serializeJson(doc, Serial);

  Serial.write("\n");
}
```

Comment: How do you receive the JSON? What `capacity` do you specify when receiving? Do you remember to provide enough capacity to fit the full body of the JSON as well?

Comment: I receiving it just by oberserving it with in serial monitor in the Arduino IDE. Later I want to receive it with an serial port in Node-Red. How can I specify a capacity while receiving ?